# python redis-queue: Simple example from documentaion not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, queue, message-queue

I have two files, literally copy-pasted from http://python-rq.org/docs/:

app.py

```
    from rq import Queue
    from redis import Redis
    from somewhere import count_words_at_url
    import time

    # Tell RQ what Redis connection to use
    redis_conn = Redis()
    q = Queue(connection=redis_conn)  # no args implies the default queue

    print(redis_conn)
    # Delay execution of count_words_at_url('http://nvie.com')
    job = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')
    print(job.result)   # => None

    # Now, wait a while, until the worker is finished
    time.sleep(10)
    print(job.result)   # => 889
```

---

somewhere.py

```
import requests
def count_words_at_url(url):
    print("hello?")
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

I ran `app.py` , and the output I got was 2 None values, as opposed to a 889 which I'm supposed to get according to the docs.

I'm not sure I understand why this is happening. My timeout is 10 seconds, and it's longer than what's in the doc, so I was expecting the job to have finished working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isolating, does `count_words_at_url('http://nvie.com')` return 889 on it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is Redis server running?

   service redis-server status
2. Is rq worker running?

   rq info

if no worker running, then

```
rq worker # run this under the same directory of your project
18:44:54 RQ worker 'rq:worker:ubuntu.45276' started, version 0.12.0
18:44:54 *** Listening on default...
18:44:54 Cleaning registries for queue: default
```

3. replace count_words_at_url with simpler function, such as

   def just_mock(url):
   time.sleep(5)
   return "count words for {} is ??".format(url)